# Splitting file based on variable

Tags: sed, split, awk, grep

I have a file with several lines of the following:

```
DELIMITER ;
```

I want to create a separate file for each of these sections.
The man page of split command does not seem to have such option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The split command only splits a file into blocks of equal size (maybe except for the last one).
However, awk is perfect for your type of problem. Here's a solution example.

### Sample input

```
1
2
3
DELIMITER ;
4
5
6
7
DELIMITER ;
8
9
10
11
```

### awk script `split.awk`

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  n = 1;
  outfile = n;
}
{
  # FILENAME is undefined inside the BEGIN block
  if (outfile == n) {
    outfile = FILENAME n;
  }
  if ($0 ~ /DELIMITER ;/) {
    n++;
    outfile = FILENAME n;
  } else {
    print $0 >> outfile;
  }
}
```

As pointed out by glenn jackman, the code also can be written as:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  n = 1;
}
$0 ~ /DELIMITER ;/ {
  n++;
  next;
}
{
  print $0 >> FILENAME n;
}
```

The notation on the command prompt `awk -v x="DELIMITER ;" -v n=1 '$0 ~ x {n++; next} {print > FILENAME n}'` is more suitable if you don't use the script more often, however you can also save it in a file as well.

### Test run

```
$ ls input*
input
$ chmod +x split.awk
$ ./split.awk input
$ ls input*
input  input1  input2  input3
$ cat input1
1
2
3
$ cat input2
4
5
6
7
$ cat input3
8
9
10
11
```

The script is just a starting point. You probably have to adapt it to your personal needs and environment.

Comment: +1 but it can be written as concisely as `awk -v x="DELIMITER ;" -v n=1 '$0 ~ x {n++; next} {print > FILENAME n}'`

Comment: This is really concise! I wasn't aware of the fact that any pattern can precede a statement block. Thanks.